# Import Repo to existing intelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft

me and my team are currently working on our Minecraft Server and we want to share all projects together. We only upload the src so we need to import the src to a existing project. How do I do that? EDIT: I have an empty existing project and a src folder in my Github repository. I want to import this folder to the empty project, edit it and update it later to the GitHub repo. So is it possible to like connect a github repo to a existing file?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to explain where youi are stuck exactly ?

Comment: I did update the post now